# How to enable function while matplotlibs zoom to rectangle is activated?

Tags: python, matplotlib

On a tkinter canvas I added the matplotlib navigation toolbar and plotted several lines which I want to pick and modify using a function. I also want to be able to zoom into the canvas and select the lines without activating and deactivating the 'zoom to rectangle' everytime I want to excecute the defined function. Is there a way to simultaneously use matplotlib's zoom function and my defined function?

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
nav = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

x = np.arange(10)
ax.plot(x, x, picker=True)
ax.plot(x, 2 * x, picker=True)
ax.plot(x, 3 * x, picker=True)
ax.plot(x, 4 * x, picker=True)

def _onPick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    thisline.set_linewidth(5)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', _onPick)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There probably is, but it would be much more complicated than what you have now. You can connect a `"button_press_event"` and find out yourself if the click occured at a place that is covered by a line.

Comment: I assume foregoing the navigation toolbar and defining my own zoom function where mouse buttons are connected to different functions could be the easiest solution. I was just hoping that there is a quite simple solution. Thank you for your opinion!

Comment: ...well, not as complicated as your custom zoom function would be. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect a `"button_press_event"` and find out yourself if the click occured at a place that is covered by a line. That is slightly more complicated than using the inbuilt picker.

```
x = np.arange(10)
ax.plot(x, x, picker=6)
ax.plot(x, 2 * x, picker=6)
ax.plot(x, 3 * x, picker=15)
ax.plot(x, 4 * x, picker=1)

def _onPick(event):
    update = False
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        for line in ax.lines:
             if line.get_picker():
                 cont, ind = line.contains(event)
                 if cont:
                     line.set_linewidth(5)
                     update=True
    if update:
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('button_press_event', _onPick)
```

Note that I redefined the picker to state a radius here, which might be useful to make sure one actually hits a line.

Comment: This is perfect! After reading some matplotlib docs there still remains one question regarding your code. `line.get_picker()` returns the integers 6, 6, 15 and 1 for all four lines but I don't understand what they mean. Do you know an explanation?

Comment: As I commented, this is the radius I set. You don't need that, if you don't want to.

Comment: Ah! I read the note but didn't notice the change, sorry. Using a radius is very helpful aswell!